# Prestashop Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

i use prestashop 1.5.6, i tryed to follow [this tutorial](http://emilienmalbranche.fr/prestashop-ecommerce-tutoriels/tutoriels/afficher-image-secondaire-survol-produits-prestashop/) .

It works but it also give me this error 24 times on the top of the page :

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /home/deveskemhu/www/classes/Category.php on line 3157

i had to add this before the last brace :

```
   public static function getProductsImgSupp($product_id)

   {

    $sql = '

    SELECT id_image, id_product from `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image`

    WHERE id_product="'.$product_id.'"

    ORDER BY `position` ASC

    LIMIT 1,1

    ';

    $result = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);

    return $result[0]['id_product'].'-'.$result[0]['id_image'];

    }
```

Line 3157 is the one before the closing brace in the code above.

what can i do to fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried to `print_r($result)` to see the data it holds?

Comment: i will right now.

Comment: instead of 26 lines of error i have now 52.

Comment: Yes because 26 lines are from the `return` and +26 from the `print_r()`

Comment: Use that.. `$result = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql); print_r($result); return;`

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_image] => 3126 [id_product] => 860 ) ) Array ( ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_image] => 3150 [id_product] => 835 ) ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_image] => 4946 [id_product] => 2939 ) ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( )

Comment: So your return is this -> `860-3126` . Do you call this function more that one time? The first item has `[0]` but the rest are almost empty.

Comment: Try this -> `if(isset($result[0])){ return $result[0]['id_product'].'-'.$result[0]['id_image']; }` . That means return it only if the array contains an index `[0]` - in other words if it contains any data

Comment: It works, i let post your solution so i can validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because not every `$result` has an index `[0]` - means its empty

Add the `if` statement line first to check if it is empty or not :

```
public static function getProductsImgSupp($product_id)

{

    $sql = '

    SELECT id_image, id_product from `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image`

    WHERE id_product="'.$product_id.'"

    ORDER BY `position` ASC

    LIMIT 1,1

    ';

    $result = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);

    if(isset($result[0])){

        return $result[0]['id_product'].'-'.$result[0]['id_image'];

    }

    // Here you could put an else in case it's empty

}
```

Comment: Awesome, I have tried your solution and it works like a charm even when I upgraded to **PHP7.3.5**.

```if(isset($result[0])){
name=$result[0];
}```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
public static function getProductsImgSupp($product_id) {

$sql = '

SELECT id_image FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image`

WHERE id_product="'.$product_id.'"

ORDER BY `position`';

$id_image = Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql);

return $product_id.'-'.$id_image;

}
```

Regards